# Erro ao mudar aplicação de H2 para PostgreSQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Estava desenvolvendo uma aplicação em banco `H2` apenas para testes e estava tudo funcionando.

Ao finalizar a implementação mudei a conexão do `JPA` para o `PostgreSQL`, só que quando fiz isso o sistema parou de persistir o objeto pessoa, me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
2015-05-31 10:57:05,395 DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] - <
    call next value for sq_pessoa_coseq>
Hibernate:
    call next value for sq_pessoa_coseq
2015-05-31 10:57:05,396 WARN [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601>
2015-05-31 10:57:05,396 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - <ERROR: syntax error at or near "call"
  Posição: 1>
```

Este é o log de *startup*:

```
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2015-05-31 10:56:35,390 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,453 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] - <Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun May 31 10:56:35 BRT 2015]; root of context hierarchy>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,483 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,665 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from file [/Users/tpoderoso/Projetos/GitHub/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/agenda/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-db.xml]>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,831 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] - <Loading properties file from file [/Users/tpoderoso/Projetos/GitHub/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/agenda/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/database.properties]>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,880 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] - <Loaded JDBC driver: org.postgresql.Driver>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,929 INFO [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] - <Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'persistencia'>
2015-05-31 10:56:35,946 INFO [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] - <HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: persistencia
        ...]>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,012 INFO [org.hibernate.Version] - <HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,013 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,014 INFO [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] - <HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,197 INFO [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] - <HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,415 INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - <HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,429 INFO [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] - <HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,455 WARN [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: br.ufscar.web.core.model.Juridica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,455 WARN [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder] - <HHH000138: Mixing inheritance strategy in a entity hierarchy is not allowed, ignoring sub strategy in: br.ufscar.web.core.model.Fisica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,536 INFO [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] - <HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,758 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,758 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <HHH000102: Fetching database metadata>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,767 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <HHH000396: Updating schema>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,772 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_endereco>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,775 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,777 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_fisica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,779 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_juridica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,781 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_endereco>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,783 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,785 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_fisica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,787 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_juridica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,789 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_endereco>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,791 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,793 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_fisica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,795 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: tb_pessoa_juridica>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,797 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: sq_endereco_coseq>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,799 INFO [java.sql.DatabaseMetaData] - <HHH000262: Table not found: sq_pessoa_coseq>
2015-05-31 10:56:36,819 INFO [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] - <HHH000232: Schema update complete>
2015-05-31 10:56:37,523 INFO [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2133 ms>
mai 31, 2015 10:56:37 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) para o contexto '/agenda'
mai 31, 2015 10:56:37 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
mai 31, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
mai 31, 2015 10:56:38 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFORMAÇÕES: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/agenda/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
mai 31, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mai 31, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mai 31, 2015 10:56:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 4226 ms
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o por que isso está ocorrendo?

**EDIÇÃO**: incluindo arquivos de configuração

**persistence.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">
        <persistence-unit name="persistencia"
                transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**database.properties**:

```
h2.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
h2.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Agenda
h2.username=tpoderoso
h2.password=1109tdp
```

**applicationContext-db.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                                <property name="database" value="H2" />
                        </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistencia" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                <property name="driverClassName" value="${h2.driverClassName}" />
                <property name="url" value="${h2.url}" />
                <property name="username" value="${h2.username}" />
                <property name="password" value="${h2.password}" />
        </bean>

        <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

Comment: Por este log ainda está usando o dialeto do `H2`. Tem como atualizar com o seu `persistence.xml` e o *application context* do spring, para vermos as configurações?

Comment: Olá Bruno, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Segue o persistence.xml (http://pastebin.com/rpYhtETj) e o applicationContext (http://pastebin.com/ivRz22gq)  e meu database.properties (http://pastebin.com/G72MH1Ms)

Comment: Veja se a reposta incluída lhe ajuda Thiago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme dito nos comentários ainda está usando o dialeto `Hibernate` para o `H2`, como mostra o log:

```
2015-05-31 10:56:36,415 INFO [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - <HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect>
```

Não é necessário especificar o dialeto a ser usado pelo `Hibernate`, caso você não especifique qual ele deve usar, ele tentará escolher o dialeto mais apropriado de acordo com a conexão.

Como você especificou o dialeto do `H2` ele irá considerar tal dialeto tanto para `DDL` quanto para `DML` e há diferenças da *linguagem* usada pelo `H2` e pelo `PostgreSQL`. Você pode ver isto verificando o fonte do dialeto do [`H2`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/H2Dialect.java) e do `PostgreSQL`.

Caso você queira especificar o dialeto para o `PostgreSQL`, estão disponíveis estes (considerando a versão estável mais recente):

- [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL81Dialect.html)
- [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect.html)
- [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL9Dialect.html)
- [org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html)

Pela sua configuração você não está fazendo isto diretamente, mas está dizendo ao Spring (através do *JPA Vendor*) que está usando o `H2` e ele está informando ao `Hibernate` o dialeto errado. Veja nesta linha do seu `applicationContext-db.xml`:

```xml
<property name="database" value="H2" />
```

Na [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/AbstractJpaVendorAdapter.html#setDatabase-org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database-) você pode verificar quais são suportados pelo vendor. Então, para que o dialeto correto seja usado, altere para isto:

```xml
<property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
```

Com isto o Spring irá "falar" ao `Hibernate` qual dialeto ele deve utilizar, ou seja, agora será o do `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: Olá Bruno!
Fiz a modificação no applicationContext que você comentou, ficando dessa maneira (http://pastebin.com/e8GgBSD6), mas ainda está retornando erro (http://pastebin.com/YhnysBWH)

Novamente, agradeço seu auxílio!

Comment: @Thiago neste log não tem erro e está agora usando o dialeto correto (`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`). Tente apagar seu banco e criar outro, para o `Hibernate` criar as tabelas do "zero" usando o novo dialeto.

Comment: É, recriei o banco, mas mesmo assim ele não persiste o objeto.

Comment: @Thiago e dá erro? O que acontece depois que ele chama `nextval` das *sequences* ? Da forma que está configurado ele tem que gerar o *DML* do *insert*.

Comment: Então ele só me da esse output (http://pastebin.com/HcWwbH5X) e não persiste

Comment: @Thiago só com isto é impossível de ajudar, não é erro agora, não está persistindo por que não dado `flush`, então está em "memória" ainda. Atualiza a sua pergunta com o método que você usa para persistir o objeto, mas não tem erro agora, não tem nada a ver com seu erro inicial.

Comment: @Thiago não é recomendado, mas como não dá para fazer tudo em uma pergunta apenas, adicione isto ao seu `persistence.xml`: `<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />`. Sugiro dar uma estudada mais a fundo em como funciona `JPA` também.

Comment: Joia Bruno, eu vou tentar aqui, deve ser algo que deixei pra trás!
Com certeza após mexer tanto no código devo ter feito algo errado, vou puxar novamente o projeto e fazer aqui.
A questão que você levantou já resolve o primeiro problema! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: @Thiago Sim, se for outro erro poste também, pode ajudar outras pessoas =)

Comment: Bruno! Era erro meu mesmo, não marquei o campo como obrigatório e ele tava como obrigatório.... Novamente, muito obrigado pelo auxílio rápido!!

Comment: @Thiago legal =)